# Django - How to prevent Custom Field Validator from executing unless the field has changed?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-admin

I have a custom validator that checks that the size of the uploaded gallery image is not too big.

This validator runs every time the model is saved no matter if the field has changed or not. This usually wouldn't be a big issue. The problem is that I have an admin panel inline, and any time I save the parent model "Profile" the validation inside of all the children "GalleryImages" gets executed. The validation of 50 images takes a long time since it needs to load all images and check for the resolution.

How can I configure this validator to only run if the field value has been updated?

```
# models.py

@deconstructible 
class ImageValidator(object): 
  """ Checks that image specs are valid """ 
  def call(self, value):
    # Some code to check for max size, width and height 
    if too_big: 
       ValidationError('Image is too big')

class Profile(Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

class GalleryImage(Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile)
    image = models.ImageField(validators=[ImageValidator])



# admin.py

class GalleryImageInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = GalleryImage

@admin.register(Profile)
class ProfileAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [GalleryImageInline]
```

Comment: I don't know if it will fix your issue, but in the `ProfileAdmin` class, it should be `inlines = [GalleryImageInline]`

Answer (score 0):

As it says in [validators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/validators/#how-validators-are-run):

> See the form validation for more information on how validators are run in forms, and Validating objects for how they’re run in models. **Note that validators will not be run automatically when you save a model, but if you are using a ModelForm, it will run your validators on any fields that are included in your form.** See the ModelForm documentation for information on how model validation interacts with forms.

It has to run validators for each object every time you save the form, and makes sense, but in your special case, you would have to implement a way to check if the image has already been validated to skip the validation, OR store the data you want to validate and access the data instead of the image (resolution, aspect, size, etc).

For example you can overwrite [save_model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-methods):

```
@admin.register(Profile)
class ProfileAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [GalleryImageInline]

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        # If a field value updates, validate
```

If you wanna upload multiple files at once check this: [file-uploads](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/http/file-uploads/#uploading-multiple-files)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why are using  `GalleryImageInline` if you don't intend to use validators to execute?

If you want to just display the gallery here is a possible solution.

```
@admin.register(Profile)
class ProfileAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    change_form_template = "yourappname/profile.html"
    
    def change_view(self, request, object_id, form_url='', extra_context=None):
        if extra_context is None:
            extra_context = {}

        gallery_images = GalleryImage.objects.filter(profile=object_id)
        if gallery_images:
            extra_context['gallery_images'] = gallery_images

        return super().change_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context=extra_context)
```

Then override change form template. Create profile.html in your app template folder.

```
profile.html

        {% block after_related_objects %}{% endblock %}

        {% block submit_buttons_bottom %}{% submit_row %}{% endblock %}
        
        //TODO write your gallery display logic here or any where you want
```

One thing to remember is that you would not be able to change the `GalleryImage` for the profile.

Answer (score -2):

use this function

```
def file_size(value):
    limit = 2 * 1024 * 1024
    if value.size > limit:
       raise ValidationError("File too large. Size should not exceed 2 MB.")
```

use this in a model like this `validators=[file_size]`

Comment: I dont think you even read the question